# Typescript same key but different type nested (keyof but nested)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to created a custom type that replaces all types of a Generic parameter T to `string[]` but keeps all the property names even nested.

Expected behaviour: No error

```
interface Bar {
    lat: string,
    lng: string
}
interface Foo {
    id: string,
    bar: Bar
}
export type PartialDeepKeyOf<T> = { [id in keyof T]: string[] }

const baz: PartialDeepKeyOf<Foo> = {
    id: ['a','b'],
    bar: {
        lat: ['a','b'],
        lng: ['a','b'],
    }
}
```

Actual behaviour:

> Type '{ lat: string[]; lng: string[]; }' is not assignable to type
> 'string[]'

Comment: Yes but "I am trying to create a custom type that replaces all types of a Generic parameter T to string[] but keeps all the property names even nested."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need recursive type traversal

```
type PartialDeepKeyOf<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends string
    ? string[]
    : PartialDeepKeyOf<T[P]>
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJysg3gKGf5AGzjAC5kBnMKUAcwBo8DCRbyqbWcBfHUSWIhQAxAPajsTfMAAm7anUYFkAIwzl0UHjhxgAngAcUABQxhgcQgBEIEAwGkIegPIwAPABUAfMgC8k5QBtY2RQZABrJ1EYZA8AXXIPYLjkCAAPSBAZCkoFLmUAflzOWkC4qWRyUyhzSxs7Rxd3JOM4rx4Abh0EURAqVTgALyqzC2tbBydXNzFRH39cZVlyQIByOFX6ZFWVVbilAjUockXlZhIV9c3t3f2K5RY2ZDWNrZ29g-xebiA)

Comment: This works well, but relies on all the leaf properties being of a type string to be converted to the new type. I could extend that to `string | number` and other primitive types, but then becomes brittle if I have to list out any enums I use as well. Is there any way to change the condition to be something like `extends Object` and then otherwise have the type converted to the new type? I can't figure out how to do that in TypeScript.

Comment: If I use `extends Record<string, any>`, this loses the enforcement of the correct key structure.

Comment: @MattTreichel If I understand you correctly, then [this should work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKsDOAXAouaBvAUFHUCGANNrgEZG5QDGmAvppgJYiLABOAZnpcFAEJ6soWCgBs8iAFxQ0JNuVwiQAcylJWTJfJzwA9hGBS4SVJFqNmbTtygAxHTqHEcDACarE65VqgkBU-qxmmIgAngAOPAAKAogMeCIAIsDAYQDSwCEA8uwAPDAAfFAAvI4UANqRUExQANYZOuywALqGFU1QwAAeLCAu8FA6JABWwJSITlAA-FDRrLHxSSnpWbkwbfkT7p5KZU20ANz0oRFQAHLAAO4w4Twls-OJyWkZ2Tl2OvmHmJQ6IEg+eAAXlJzlcbsVSrhXFIygByPCwghQWEkWFNby+VhSYQUBTiGHwxHI1HoiaiZQEhFIlFo7wUXT6SlEmmkih0GhAA).

Comment: Thanks, that probably does, it turns out my editor's error reporting made me think it wasn't working as intended. I spun this question off into a new thread here because I was impatient: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72692468/1917171