# Create a type with the same nested keys as another type but all values are string

Tags: typescript

I have a type like the following,

```js
interface SomeType {
  prop1: number,
  prop2: string,
  prop3: SomeEnum,
  prop4: {
    nestedProp1: number
  }
}

enum SomeEnum {
  value1,
  value2,
  value3,
}
```

and I want a similar type with all the same nested structure, but where every value is `string` (or maybe some other type).

I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63111720/1917171, which gets me partly there, but relies on every leaf value already being a consistent type. In my real life situation I use many different enums as values, so it would be brittle to use conditional typing with a union of every possible value to replace `extends string`.

Comment: What is `SomeEnum`?  Can you provide a [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE?

Comment: @jcalz Sure I guess, I've added a definition, the structure of it isn't all that important other than being a standard TypeScript enum.

Comment: Also, I foresee edge cases galore here.  How do you decide whether to replace with `string` or traverse downward?  If you transform `{foo: Date}`, do you expect `{foo: string}` or `{foo: {getTime: string; getFullYear: string; ...}}`?

Comment: The simple/naive implementation looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDyeVm), but oh boy are there edge cases.  What do you want to see with union properties? Index signatures? Optional properties? Etc etc etc

Comment: I guess I would be assuming I want to replace any primitive values - an enum resolves to a primitive, unlike Date, which is not.

In my real life situation I know this object only has primitives and sub-objects and nothing like Date or Functions, so if that wasn't handled it would be fine.

Comment: So does the version in my previous comment work for you, or are there use cases that it doesn't handle?  Could you test it out and get back to me?

Comment: @jcalz Ah. I was going to say it didn't work, because it was letting me add additional keys that weren't part of the original object, but it turns out that's something to do with my TypeScript checker only resolving one error at a time - it was distracted by other keys with non-string values, as intended. I guess that makes this a valid answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is

```
type PrimitivesToString<T> =
  T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: PrimitivesToString<T[K]> } : string
```

which is a [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) type that either turns `T` into `string` (if it's primitive, a.k.a., not `extends object`), or recursively [maps](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) each property the same way.

This works as intended for your example use case:

```
type Transformed = PrimitivesToString<SomeType>;
/* type Transformed = {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: string;
    prop3: string;
    prop4: {
        nestedProp1: string;
    };
} */
```

But you should be careful to thoroughly test with other use cases, as such recursive type transformations tend to have some possibly surprising behaviors.  For example, what should happen in the face of [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)-typed properties?

```
type DesiredOrNot = PrimitivesToString<{ a: number | { b: number } }>;
/* type DesiredOrNot = { a: string | { b: string; }; } */
```

If the type `number | {b: number}` a primitive, or a non-primitive, or do you want to [distribute](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) the type function across each piece of the union so that each part transforms separately?  I think distribution across unions is natural, but it might not be suitable for particular purposes.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&jsx=0&preserveWatchOutput=false&noErrorTruncation=true&ts=4.7.2&ssl=24&ssc=19&pln=23&pc=19#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYOAgbhAzgFQPYDKwiAdgOYA8OAfFALwBQUUOUEAHsBCQCZZR4ARgCsIAY2BQA-FADeUANoBpKAhJQA1hBB4AZiwC6ALliIUaTLkLE1lHMoO0AvlBNYb5Bl7Vc4ugIZi0AR4SBA44NCyTFBgcHhgAIwmJACuSIIQcAA0MXEJAExuHmS5zPlgAMwmIWEAomlIZbHxYAAsJtHMzCTYXDzwCclQjZlwMU4Mkwzc6VC1EA1zXVDo-gA2qRCJzWubEAW7G1uVudOgkCxw-iRYunhwYTz0psioGNj4RKSUCxGQ1AA3AwAPQAKigF2gOGut3ujwgzzochi5Vaw3cP2B3RahWKWNRuKq+Ns2O6FQ6KJxON67kRgySJPIZOYTmBLjBIK8UKgABFsAg4IiAPJwAByeEkyPgbwsn2sPwo8n8KXSYygAB85FBBKqMlkoC4nEDQRCefysIKReLJS9lUyyJrtbqoJjSYbAYaoJygA)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be effective and that's a great caveat. I'm not particularly sure myself, I don't personally have that use case - but I imagine distribution is most useful as well.

Comment: In practice, we did forget one other obvious edge case: Arrays extend Object as well. I had a co-worker suggest this modification: `type PrimitivesToString<T> = T extends (infer U)[] ? PrimitivesToString<U>[] : T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: PrimitivesToString<T[K]> } : string;`. Definitely not as graceful, you're right it's not as simple as you'd think.

Comment: Arrays should map to arrays already, did you test it out?  [Looks fine to me](https://tsplay.dev/WoaYLN).

Comment: Yeah, as is it seems to require the object to define all the built-in properties of the array with strings like length and so on.

Answer (score 2):

```js
interface SomeType {
  prop1: number
  prop2: string
  prop3: SomeEnum
  prop4: {
    nestedProp1: number
  }
}

enum SomeEnum {
  value1,
  value2,
  value3,
}

type ToString<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? ToString<T[K]> : string
}

/*
If you need to take care of built-in types
type Primitive = null | undefined | string | number | boolean | symbol | bigint
type ToString<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Primitive | Date | File | FileList ? string : ToString<T[K]>
}
*/

const foo: ToString<SomeType> = {
  prop1: 'string',
  prop2: 'string',
  prop3: 'string',
  prop4: {
    nestedProp1: 'string',
  },
}
```

Comment: I don't know if OP cares about unions...should `{a: number | {b: number}}`  transform to `{a: string}` or `{a: string | {b: string}}`?